# Convert Python Request to Microsoft Power BI M code

Tags: python, python-requests, powerbi, powerquery, m

I would like to convert a request from Python code to M used in Power BI Power Query

My Python code is

\\

import requests
import datetime as dt

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer tok_123', 'Accept': 'text/csv'}

url = 'https://api.123/'

params = (
('start_time', start_date),
('end_time', tomorrow),
)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

data = response.text

\\

The M code I have made (which does not work) is below.  Could you let me know where I am going wrong?

Am getting error 400 invalid request.  I think there is something wrong with the way I am translating params.

\\

let

apiUrl = "https://api.123/",
     
options = [Headers =[#"Authorization"="Bearer tok_123", #"start_time"="2021-01-05", #"end_time"="2021-02-05"]],
     
result = Web.Contents(apiUrl , options)

in

result

\\

Thanks

Comment: Should not it be `print(response.text)` {or `print(data)`}?

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting a 400

See the sections below, "verifying request", and "error code details"

Without your url, or the docs, I don't know what endpoint you're using, so here's an example

```
HTTP GET https://www.example.com/api/user/search?limit=1000&region=US
```

## Using RelativePath and Query

Note: It's important to use `options[RelativePath]` and `options[Query]` to prevent **service refresh errors** on the service. Check out [docs: Web.Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents#__toc360793395)

```
let 
    Headers = [
        Accept="application/json"
    ],
    BaseUrl = "https://www.example.com",
    Options = [
        RelativePath = "/api/user/search",
        Headers = Headers,
        Query = [
            limit = 1000,
            region = "US"                    
    ],
    Response = Web.Contents(BaseUrl, Options),
    Result = Json.Document(Response) // skip if it's not JSON
in
    Result
```

## Authorization

Setting `options[ApiKeyName]`lets you specify your API token / password using the credential store instead of in the code itself.

Otherwise you can set it using the `Headers` `record` just like you are in python.

## Error Code details

For details, first specify the HTTP Status codes you want to handle

```
Options = [
    // add this param to Options
    ManualStatusHandling = {"400"}
]
```

Then view error details in the `metadata`

```
details = Value.Metadata(Response)
```

## Verifying Request

You can view the actual HTTP requests fired by either using

- [Query Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/recordingquerydiagnostics#diagnose-step) which is built in,
- or a tool like [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)